# Comparing wchar_t with hex value

Tags: c, wchar-t

I have a problem when comparing wchar_t with hex value.

```
wchar_t c;
FILE *f = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
fwscanf(f, L"%lc", &c); // c is 'ệ'
printf("%d", c == L'\0x1ec7');
```

'ệ' is 0x1ec7 hex. But the result is 0. And how to compare wchar_t with hex value?

Comment: Yes, my first guess is that the comparison is correct, and `c` does not contain what you think.  You can try assigning the value to `c` directly in place of the file read, to better test the comparison.

Comment: tenerg, Try again without the leading 0:`L'\x1ec7'`

Comment:    I should have seen that!  No **compiler warning** about a multi-character character literal?

Comment: JDlugosz, I use VS2013 and no compiler warning.

Comment: Interesting... MSVC C compiler does not give a warning, but gcc (as C++) does give a warning about the literal being too long for its type.

Comment: @JDługosz IIRC MSVC specifically has a multi-character literal extension (assuming my memory is correct, I think I saw it on a SO post and I've never used MSVC personally), so the compiler probably saw this is OP trying to simply use the extension. IDK if MSVC has any option like `-pedantic-errors` that forbids the use of such extensions.

Comment: @JDługosz of course [MSVC does warn about that](https://godbolt.org/z/o465xx4sd) but you need to supply at least `/W3` option (which is the default in VS 2019). However VS 2013 is an extremely outdated compiler and may have that at a higher warning level, or didn't support that warning at all. In short, avoid those ancient compilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct notation is `L'\x1ec7'`, not `L'\0x1ec7'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  wchar_t const c = L'ệ';
  printf("%d", c == L'\x1ec7'); // prints 1
}
```